# Java Bitwise & operator multiple permission

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I am working on a java web application and in a database table i have a column of type number. but that column is for storing the multiple values . (ie Permission like below)

1. nothing = 1;
2. view = 2;
3. add = 4;
4. edit = 8;
5. insert = 16;
6. delete = 32;
7. all = 64;

Problem

1. if that column has value 3 --> then i need to pick nothing,view as
   permission .
2. if that column has value 12 --> then i need to pick add ,
       edit.

something like this

I undserstood like we can do this by bitwise operator . Any code to acheive this would be great .

Comment: Why is "nothing" a value at all? Why not just take 0 as being "no permissions"? Also, you could use an enum instead and rely on ordinals, although {de,}serializing it {from,to} the database may be a challenge. And why is "all" a distinct value as well?

Comment: Any problem using equality operator ? `value == 3`

Comment: I would consider using a BitSet (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), and simply calling `get()` to check if a bit is set..

Comment: Also, how do you deal with an int which has both "nothing" and "all"?

Comment: Nothing meaning no permision and all is everything except nothing

Comment: My [first result from google using your exact question title](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html) gives more details than anyone would actually need to implement the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the response . I created a simple utility with bitand operator that is working great for the above usecase

Problem:

1 ) getPermission(3) will return nothing and view.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getPermission(int day) {
    List<Integer> places = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64);
    ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer i : places) {
        if (bitWiseAnd(day, i)) {
            d.add(i);
        }
    }
    return d;
}

public static boolean bitWiseAnd(int bitwise, int operator) {
    return (bitwise & operator) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean bitwise OPERATIONS and binary literals.

In your case, you would have to use a bitmask (fixed version, thank you @Paul Boddington & @Jaroslaw Pawlak) :

```
final int MASK_NOTHING = 1;
final int MASK_VIEW = 0b10;
final int MASK_ADD = 0b100;
final int MASK_EDIT = 0b1000;
final int MASK_INSERT = 0b10000;
final int MASK_DELETE = 0b100000;
final int MASK_ALL = 0b1000000;
int column = 0; //YOUR DATA HERE

if((column & MASK_NOTHING) > 0)
{

}

if((column & MASK_VIEW) > 0)
{

}
```

mind you : all of the possible bitflags can be set independently ... so either prevent setting more than one at a time or handle all of these cases

Binary literals : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html Operators : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: This is the right way to go except that OP should use 0 as nothing, and `&` together all possible permissions to use as `MASK_ALL` instead of using a hard coded value. Pretty standard stuff actually had OP done some research first.

Comment: well there is no "right" way to go ... but it is one of the fastest algorithms for this job - for usability reasons individuals could choose the other answer

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston yes, but `|`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your set of permissions is really strange; "nothing" and "all" being separated value is, uh.

Well, you could use an enum and rely on ordinals; it's kind of hackish but it can work. Sample code:

```
public enum Permission
{
    NOTHING,
    VIEW,
    ADD,
    EDIT,
    INSERT,
    DELETE,
    ALL,
    ;

    private static final Set<Permission> ALL_PERMISSIONS;

    static {
        final Set<Permission> set = values();
        set.remove(NOTHING);
        set.remove(ALL);
        ALL_PERMISSIONS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
    }

    private static final int NOTHING_ORDINAL = NOTHING.ordinal();
    private static final int ALL_ORDINAL = ALL.ordinal();

    public static Set<Permission> fromInt(final int value)
    {
        int mask;

        mask = 1 << NOTHING_ORDINAL;
        if (value & mask == mask)
            return Collections.emptySet();

        mask = 1 << ALL_ORDINAL;
        if (value & mask == mask)
            return ALL_PERMISSIONS;

        final Set<Permission> set = EnumSet.noneOf(Permission.class);

        for (final Permission p: ALL_PERMISSIONS) {
            mask = 1 << p.ordinal();
            if (value & mask == mask)
                set.add(p);
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
    }
}
```

---

Now, why this work: it is because the `.ordinal()` of an `Enum` value is its index of appearance in the enum. Here, `NOTHING` has ordinal 0 and `ALL` has ordinal 6. Therefore, if you were to map an int to a set of permissions, you'd have to check that for any permission p, the p-th bit in the integer is set. Which, in turn, means that `i & (1 << p.ordinal()) == 1 << p.ordinal()`.

Fore more information, see the javadoc of `Enum`.

---

**DESIGN CONSIDERATION**: do NOT store "nothing" and "all" as possible values. Both of them can be mapped to integers:

- 0 for no permissions:
- all values for view, add, etc for all permissions (basically, since here you have 5 permissions in total, the value would be (1 << 5) - 1).

Comment: this logic depends on the ordinal enum value being the same for all eternity - or else the algorithm will break.

Comment: @specializt and this is the case. Read the documentation of `EnumSet`.

Comment: @fge am getting some error in your code if (value & mask)
                set.add(p); and if (value & mask == mask) , if (value & mask == mask) . am using the java 1.6

Comment: so you actually claim that you know the ordinal values for his code for all eternity?

Comment: @specializt fixed; and yes, the ordinals won't change. The "worst" case is if the set of permissions can change over time, but then this is why it is counterproductive to store "nothing" and "all" as possible values!

Comment: @fge : ordinal value will change if you add an item at any position but the end, like if you add a new permission between "INSERT" and "DELETE". Though, I agree this should not happen if future developers take the time to understand the enum.

Comment: @fge i think you need to do some trial-and-error now.

Comment: @Gaël yes, I'm aware ;) But you _do_ have to put _some_ faith in developers :p

Comment: @fge code has some error in line final Set<Permission> set = values();
is this code running in your machine . am using java 1.6

Comment: you really should upgrade ... java 1.6 is VERY old and almost all JRE6 application will work with JRE8

Comment: sure will change in next time . need solution as of now